# Deploying python-gst. Pyinstaller on windows fails on gi package - DLL load failed

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-gstreamer

I'm trying to deploy a program running the binding of gstreamer in python (python-gst). Im using pyinstaller for this. Im running windows 7, python-2.7 64 bits. Heres a minimal working example - pyinstallertest.py:

```py
import gi

print 'hello world'
```

I then run `pyinstaller foo.spec` without any errors or warning, where foo.spec is the following file:

```py
import os
gst_plugin_path = os.environ.get('GST_PLUGIN_PATH').split('lib')[0]
a = Analysis(['.\\pyinstallertest.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\pyinstaller_test'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='pytest.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )


coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('./'),
               Tree(gst_plugin_path),
               Tree(os.path.join(gst_plugin_path, 'bin')),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='pytest')
```

When running the generated pytest.exe in \dist\pytest\ it fails with the following error:

```
File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 412, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this, or alternative ways to deploy a python program in windows that contains gstreamer (and the gi package) ?